# Filter ng-repeat elements from the beginning of the string

Tags: angularjs, filter

I'm experimenting with AngularJS, this is my first try. I'm trying to filter an array of objects using something like "starts with" rather than "contains", but I'm not understanding how to do that.

Let's say that I have an `elements` array like this

```
[{
  amount: 50
}, {
  amount: 25
}]
```

If I want to filter by `5` both records will be shown, while I just want to have the first one, the one that starts with `5`.

This is what I've done so far, for the looping part (I've also added the ordering and paging part, even if maybe isn't influencing what I'm trying to achieve)

```
<tr ng-repeat="element in elements | filter:search:strict | orderBy:predicate:reverse | filter:startFrom:currentPage*pageSize | limitTo:pageSize">
  <td>{{element.name}}</td>
  <td>{{hotel.amount}}</td>
</tr>
```

and for the input where I write the "`5`"

```
<input class="pull-right" ng-model="search.amount">
```

I'm not understanding how to create a custom handler here, so that I can parse each nth item and see if it starts with the passed number.

Comment: Your data model contains integers, but you're attempting a string-type filter on it. I believe you'll need to use a custom comparator function in your filter that first converts the integers to strings.

Comment: Several ways to approach..can filter data in controller or create custom filter for use in markup. Are you wanting to search specific property of objects only?

Comment: @XMLilley ok, how do I start with it?

Comment: @charlietfl let's start with what will work in this example. I need to understand the AngularJS way of doing this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would just write basic custom filter:

**JS**

```
var iApp = angular.module("App", []);

 iApp.filter('myfilter', function() {

   function strStartsWith(str, prefix) {
    return (str+"").indexOf(prefix) === 0;
   }


   return function( items, amount) {


    var filtered = [];

    angular.forEach(items, function(item) {
      if(strStartsWith(item.amount, amount)){
        filtered.push(item);
      }
    });

    return filtered;
  };
});

    iApp.controller('TestController', function($scope)
    {   
       $scope.amount='';

       $scope.elements = [
         { amount: 50},
         { amount: 25 }];                
     });
```

**HTML**

```
<body data-ng-controller="TestController">

  <input class="pull-right" ng-model="amount">

        <table id="hotels">
            <tr data-ng-repeat="element in elements | myfilter:amount">
                <td>{{element.amount}}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <br/>

    </body>
```

Demo <kbd>**[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/4zIBlV20ysym3L0OhL3B?p=preview)**</kbd>

Comment: I'm trying to integrate this into my app, is there a way to have clearer errors in AngularJS ? They seems a bit cryptic. I'm currently getting this "Error: [$injector:unpr] errors.angularjs.org/1.2.2/$injector/unpr?p0=myFilterFilterProvider%20%3C-%20myFilterFilter"

Comment: The whole last part of that error is a URL. Visit the URL... and voilà.

Comment: Thanks for this, I'm trying it out.

Answer (score 4):

Maxim's answer helped me, but I thought I'd chip in with a slightly more general solution for filtering either a flat list or a list of objects where you want to filter on a specific property.

**[View Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/56sY6w3MgaSGKPJfrXzx?p=preview)**

```
/**
 * Filter a list for elements with start with the given string.
 * 
 * @param {Array} items - The list of items to filter
 * @param {String} prefix - The prefix to search for
 * @param {String} [itemProperty] - An optional property to use for the search
 *                                  if filtering a list of objects.
 */
.filter('startsWith', function() {
  return function(items, prefix, itemProperty) {
    return items.filter(function(item) {
      var findIn = itemProperty ? item[itemProperty] : item;
      return findIn.toString().indexOf(prefix) === 0;
    });
  };
})
```

---

**Example Usage**

```
// item in flatList | startswith:<term>
var flatList = ['foo', 'bar', 'zulu']

// item in objectList | startswith:<term>:<key>
var objectList = [
  {value: 'foo', label: '-FOO-'},
  {value: 'bar', label: '-BAR-'}
];
```

---

To make case insensitive just apply `.toLowerCase()` to both the prefix and to `findIn`