# Angular js custom filter for searching with Startswith then contains for ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i am new to angular, 
in my application i have a `text box` and a list with `ng-repeat`

when the user types any thing on the text box i am filtering the 
results based on the typed text by using the following code

```
<input type=textbox ng-model="TypedText"/>

ng-repeat measure in newSearchResults |filter:TypedText
```

but the default filter in angular is providing contains search.
i need results that startswith and next contains.
i tried writing custom filters but none of those are working. help me in creating custom filter.

Comment: Already answered..Please check this,it might be helpful
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20179546/filter-ng-repeat-elements-from-the-beginning-of-the-string

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own custom filter as shown in the [documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter).

```
{{ filter_expression | filter : array : expression : comparator}}
```

You need to provide a function as an `expression` here.

So, let us say you want to filter based on whether the value "contains" the search text. You will create a function in the controller as:

```
 $scope.customFilter = function(value) {
     // value parameter is the value passed in each ng-repeat
     // In your example, it is the measure variable in "ng-repeat measure in
     // newSearchResults

     if (value.indexOf($scope.TypedText) !== -1) {
         return true;
     } else {
         return false;
     }
 };
```

If you return true in the custom filter function, that value is shown else it is not.

You can then use the custom filter like any other filter:

```
<div ng-repeat="measure in newSearchResults | filter:customFilter()">
    //Repeating tags here
</div>
```

Comment: Do not use '( )' when calling the filter 'filter:customFilter()'. Just pass the name 'filter:customFilter'

Answer (score 0):

Like mentioned in the first answer, you can pass a function to the filter, which does the check for you.

```
 $scope.customFilter = function(item) {

     var typedTextLength = ($scope.typedText) ? ($scope.typedText).length : 0,
         substring = (item.yourValueToCheck).substring(0, typedTextLength);

     return ($scope.typedText === substring);

 };
```